# PHP - prevent uploading file more than 100 KB in during uploadin file not after upload entire file

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, limit, server-side-scripting

I have an page with php code to upload user's picture for every account.Size of their image file must less than 100 kb size.

I want prevent uploading file more than 100 KB on server from users(in registering new user in image profile field) and **during uploading**(Not after uploading the entire file and just during uploading it), if the upload volume exceeds 100 KB, stop uploading progress and display warning for user by PHP(**Preferred**) OR any other script language **for server-side code**.

I searched by stackoverflow and google I didn't find any help or source about that.

Please help me

Comment: I'm quite sure PHP alone can't do that. But not sure if you need Ajax or JavaScript.

Comment: set the upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Comment: Will that stop the upload? I didn't think PHP would know the file size until the full file was uploaded

Comment: @nogad I want to display one of my own web warning to user not a system error

Comment: you can handle the error with an exception

Comment: @nogad I'm begginer in php and web designing.please say me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious option is a few lines of Javascript added to your HTML that will be your first line of defense:

```
var uploadField = document.getElementById("file");

uploadField.onchange = function() {
    if(this.files[0].size > 100000){
       alert("File is too big!");
       this.value = "";
    };
};
```

If you then also ensure that your form can only be submitted via javascript like this:

http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

That way, the user can't just turn off Javascript and upload any size they want.

It might be possible to do this by using a chunk process to upload your file in chunks instead of one big file, but I dont think I've tried to restrict filesize that way before...